# Rewrite 1st commit of a Git Repo

Tags: git, rebase

I have an old CVS repo I've converted over to GIT and in doing so I realized that some of my user names are messed up ... something i can fix with a `.mailmap` I'm also using **Atlassian Stash** and a certain plugin that allows me to see nice graphs of who committed what etc.  The problem is that accordiong to plugin instructions:

> 1. How can I merge two users with different emails who in fact are one person? Starting from Stash 2.5.0 you can use .mailmap file in the
>      repository to do this. Please, note this affects only commits made
>      after the mailmap file was added. Changing a global .mailmap file in
>      Git won't help (see details here).

So this means if i add my `.mailmap` file it won't really have any impact on my 3 years of historical commits.

I believe what I want to do is rewrite the commit history to modify the 1st commit and add the `.mailmap` file into the repo and then use a force push to overwrite what is stored on my server.

- Is this the correct approach?
- What Git commands would i have to run in order to add a `.mailmap` file and then replace my remote repo

Answer (score 0):

[Git Filter Branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)

If you are rewriting all your history anyway you can just change the Name/Email instead of using a .mailmap.

If you want to add the mailmap you would also use filter-branch, but a different form of it.  This would be something like what you want to rewrite the emails without using a mailmap

```
      git filter-branch --env-filter '

      DUP_EMAIL="email_that_you_want_to_change"
      CORRECT_EMAIL="email_you_would_rather_have"

      if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$DUP_EMAIL" ]
      then
            export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
      fi
      if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$DUP_EMAIL" ]
      then
            export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
      fi
      ' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```